# Handle multiple projects with SVN?

Tags: svn, apache

I've decided to handle all my projects using SVN, and thus I set up a windows server with XAMPP installed and installed subversion to it. I followed a tutorial (I don't remember the name) and I ended up with a folder C:/svn that contains an apache config file and all my repositories.

The trouble is: For each repository I add I have to add a bunch of lines to the apache configuration and restart apache. This is how the config file looks: (With foobar data)

```
<Location /svn/melior>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath C:/svn/melior

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Melior subversion repository"
  AuthUserFile C:/svn/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user

  AuthzSVNAccessFile C:/svn/svn-acl
</Location>

<Location /svn/urs>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath C:/svn/urs

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "URS subversion repository"
  AuthUserFile C:/svn/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user

  AuthzSVNAccessFile C:/svn/svn-acl
</Location>
```

And that's for two repositories. What I'm looking for is some way to apply this configuration to a parent folder so that every time I add a repository I can access it via apache. The simplest way to do this would be to use only one repository and add every project as a child folder of trunk.

Anyway, what are your thoughts and preferences when working with a growing collection of SVN repositories?

Comment: You could always have a look at the VisualSvn Server product: http://www.visualsvn.com/server/ which runs happily on Windows.

Comment: Well gee... That simplifies things. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `SVNParentPath` directive, to configure a directory which contains repositories.  Details in the [Subversion Manua](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic)l.